# Retrieved compared products list in homepage

Tags: magento2, compare

I like to retrieve compared product collections in homepage template. Is there any method to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts $compareProducts
) {
    $this->compareProducts = $compareProducts;
}

/*
    * Get current compare product list
    */
public function getCompareList(){
    return $this->compareProducts->getSectionData();
}
```

create one phtml file and then load in homepage container via xml.

```
<?php
    $compareObject = $block->getCompareList();
 ?>
<div class="compare-items">
<?php foreach($compareObject['items'] as $comparelist){                        
 ?>
    <div class="compProd">
        <a class="closeComp" data-href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>ajaxcompare/compare/remove/" data-compare="<?php echo $comparelist['id']; ?>">x</a>
        <span class="gBold cmPrd"><?php echo $comparelist['name']; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working for guest users.